# How to render from fetching data api (It show on console log but I can't call it in render)

Tags: react-native

I want to fetch API data from https://memegenerator.net It show the data on console log but I don't know how to called it

I try some variable in console log but it still not show anything

here fetching code

``````
  fetch("http://version1.api.memegenerator.net//Comment_Create?entityName=Instance&entityID=72628355&parentCommentID=&text=first%20post%20best%20post&apiKey=demo")
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then((responseJson)=> {
    this.setState({
     dataSource: responseJson
    })
    console.log(responseJson(commentID));
  })
  .catch(error=>console.log(error)) 
  }`````


i need it to show data if i call {this.sate.commnedId}  to show commendId
 see console log in this image [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLorh.png
``````

Comment: Maybe you need to do console.log(responseJson[commentID]) with brackets? Otherwise, please be more clear

Comment: if you use setState with "dataSource": ... , you need to get data in this.state.dataSource

Comment: you can put directly in state using setState({ ...responseJson }), considering the responseJson is correct

Comment: if you need a point to put that code, you can put at componentDidMount() function, if you're extending React.Component

Answer (score 0):

```
 componentDidMount(){
       let dataSource = '';
      fetch("http://version1.api.memegenerator.net//Comment_Create?entityName=Instance&entityID=72628355&parentCommentID=&text=first%20post%20best%20post&apiKey=demo")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then((responseJson)=> {
        this.setState({
         dataSource:responseJson.result.commentID
        })

       // console.log(responseJson.result.text); this show in console
        console.log(dataSource);
      })
      .catch(error=>console.log(error)) //to catch the errors if any
      }
```

Comment: Now I can solved the problem, for someone who confuse about my question I'm really sorry because I'm not good at English